# For loops in 2D arrays giving incorrect types in F#

Tags: f#, type-inference

I suspect that I am missing something very obvious here but this doesn't work:

```
let t = Array2D.create 1 1 1.0
for x in t do printfn "%f" x;;
```

It fails with

> error FS0001: The type 'obj' is not compatible with any of the types float,float32,decimal, arising from the use of a printf-style format string

Interestingly using `printf "%A"` or `"%O"` prints the expected values which suggests to me that the problem is with the type inference

The corresponding code for a 1D array works fine

```
let t = Array.create 1 1.0
for x in t do printfn "%f" x;;
```

For reference this is on version 2.0 (both interactive and compiler) running on the latest mono

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .NET, a 1D array implicitly implements IList, which means it also implements (by inheritance) `IEnumerable<T>`. So, when you run:

```
let t = Array.create 1 1.0
for x in t do printfn "%f" x;;
```

the F# compiler emits code which gets an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` (`seq<T>` in F#) from `t`, then iterates over it. Since it's able to get an `IEnumerable<T>` from the array, `x` will have type `T`.

On the other hand, multi-dimensional arrays (2d, 3d, etc.) only implement `IEnumerable` (not `IEnumerable<T>`) so the F# compiler infers the type of `x` as `System.Object` (or `obj`, in F#).

There are two solutions for what you want:

**Cast each individual value within the loop, before printing it:**

```
for x in t do printfn "%f" (x :?> float);;
```

**Or, use Seq.cast to create and iterate over a strongly-typed enumerator:**

```
for x in (Seq.cast<float> t) do printfn "%f" x;;
```

Comment: It is interesting that the compiler team didn't work around this with special cases for arrays

Answer (score 3):

As Jack pointed out, this is a problem. One easy solution is:

```
let t = Array2D.create 2 2 1.0
t |> Array2D.iter (printfn "%f");;
```

And if you **really** like the `for .. in .. do` syntax:

```
type Array2DForLoopBuilder() =
    member __.Zero() = ()
    member __.For(a, f) = Array2D.iter f a
    member __.Run e = e

let a2dfor = Array2DForLoopBuilder()

let t = Array2D.init 2 2 (fun a b -> float a + float b)

a2dfor { for x in t do printfn "%f" x }
```